# object hierarchy functions

Tags: c

My task would be to make this object hierarchy and have a sum of all file sizes in the file system.

If I understand correctly this would be a multi level inheritance, but I'm not sure how to write a function what can run through every lower-level object and sum them up.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class File{
public:
    //File(int x){filesize=x;}
    void setSize(int x){filesize=x;}
    void showsize(){cout<<filesize<<endl;}
    int getsize(){return filesize;}
private:
    int filesize;

};

class Directory : public File {
public:
    void SumDir(){
        
    }
private:
    int sumofdir=0;


};


int main()
{
    File b;
    b.setSize(416);
    b.showsize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably `Directory` should have a container of pointers to other directories and/or files.

Comment: This could be operating system specific. Notice that C++17 implementations have [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), but you could also use the [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) library

Answer (score 0):

You could have the `Directory` class have a `std::vector` of `File*`. Then it would be just a simple walkthrough of each of these directory entries and in turn, invoke the `getSize()` on them. `getSize()` could be a polymorphic function that just either gets the size of the `File` if it's a regular file or the size of the entire directory if it's an instance of a `Directory`. Something on these lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class File{
public:
    explicit File(int x): fileSize(x){}

    void setSize(int x){
        fileSize=x;
    }

    void showSize() const{
        std::cout<<fileSize<<'\n';
    }

    virtual size_t getSize() const{
        return fileSize;
    }

    virtual ~File() = default;
private:
    int fileSize;
};

class Directory : public File {
public:
    Directory() : File(0){} //Directory is just a File of 0 size

    size_t getSize() const override{
        size_t size = 0;
        for(auto const& file: dirEntries) {
            size += file->getSize();
        }
        return size;
    }

    void addFile(File* file) {
        if(file != nullptr) {
            dirEntries.push_back(file);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<File*> dirEntries;
};

int main() {
    Directory child;
    File f1{10}, f2{20};
    child.addFile(&f1);
    child.addFile(&f2);
    Directory parent;
    File f3{30};
    parent.addFile(&f3);
    parent.addFile(&child);
    std::cout<<parent.getSize(); //60
}
```